# Function to reverse a two-dimensional set of strings in C isn't reversing more than the first and last characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, reverse

this is my first post in Stack Overflow. If I am missing anything, please let me know and I will try to add more information.

The function below is only supposed to use pointer operations and not array operations, as part of an assignment.

I have this function in C that is part of a larger program:

```
void reverseString(char strings[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH])
{
    int i, j;
    char *ptr;                              //Declare pointer variable.
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        ptr = strings[i];
        do {                                //Here, we ignore the null terminators in the char array.
            ptr++;
        } while (*ptr != '\0');
        ptr--;                              //Iterate the pointer variable once downward.
        j = i;

        while (strings[j] < ptr)            //While loop for reversing the string
        {
            //printf("ptr: %d\n", ptr);
            //printf("strings[j]: %d\n", strings[j]);
            char temp = *strings[j];
            *strings[j++] = *ptr;
            *ptr-- = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

What it is supposed to do is accept a 2D char array with 4 strings and with each string holding up to 32 bytes of text. Then, it reverses each string in-place in the array. For example, if I input the four strings:

Hello
World
Good
morning

It is supposed to then return:

olleH
dlroW
dooG
gninrom

However, what ends up happening is that only the first and last characters of each string are reversed. For example:

oellH
dorlW
dooG
gorninm

I have tried different solutions such as using i instead of j in the while loop or using prefix ++ instead of suffix, but nothing has worked yet. Any pointers as to what I should be looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: Let's say `j` is 0. Then `strings[j]` points to "Hello". And when you increment `j`, then `strings[j]` points to "World". That's the problem. You have a char pointer `ptr` that points to the end of the string. You need another char pointer that points to the beginning of the string.

Comment: Aaah, thank you very much! You got it right. I added a second pointer instead of using strings[j] and this time it worked perfectly. Thank you again! I'll edit my post with the solution.

Comment: Well done! You can post the edit as an answer, and then accept it. That's the preferred method of showing that the question has been solved.

Comment: Note that the `do { ptr++; } while (…)` loop is going to (or, at least, could) run into major problems if processing an empty string.  You skip over the null terminator, and you've no idea what you're accessing after that.  You really what `while (*ptr != '\0') ptr++;` — or use `strlen()`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is below. As described in my comment below, I added a secondary pointer instead of using strings[j] in the loop. The pointer now references to the beginning of the string instead of the entire array of strings.

```
void reverseString(char strings[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH])
{
    int i, j;
    char *ptr;                              //Declare pointer variable.
    char *ptr2;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        ptr = strings[i];
        ptr2 = strings[i];
        do {                                //Here, we ignore the null terminators in the char array.
            ptr++;
        } while (*ptr != '\0');
        ptr--;                              //Iterate the pointer variable once downward.
        j = i;

        while (ptr2 < ptr)          //While loop for reversing the string
        {
            char temp = *ptr2;
            *ptr2++ = *ptr;
            *ptr-- = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728579/function-to-reverse-a-two-dimensional-set-of-strings-in-c-isnt-reversing-more-t#comment84457534_48728579) to the main question about the `do { ptr++; } while (…);` loop.